# C Unit Testing - Mock (In Check Framework)

Tags: c, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to "mock" some things in my unit testing of a C project.
I am using the Check framework for testing and I have a function that reads from a file on disk to verify the contents.

My function is:

```
#include "verifier.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int verify_content(char *path, char *verify_string) {
    File *fptr
    fptr = fopen(path, "r")
    // Do verification
    return 0
```

and my test is

```
START_TEST (verify_content_test)
    {
        char *test_path = "test_path";
        char *test_string = "unique_string_content_here";
        ck_assert_str_eq(verify_content(test_path, test_string), 0);
    }
END_TEST
```

However, I don't want this to read from disk, because that would be slow, and I'd have to have multiple static files just for testing against.

Is there a way to "mock"/"fake" the fopen?

I'm still new to C development and super new to unit testing in C so if I should approach this problem differently, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `fopen()` and put anything you like into it. Link this module with all other modules that need the mocked version.

The function will only be linked from the standard library if there are unresolved references. Providing your own implementation resolves all references and so the standard version will not be used.

With GCC you also have another alternative: use the linker's `--wrap` option. For example `--wrap=fopen` will change all references of `fopen()` into `__wrap_fopen()` and change the defined symbols of `fopen()` into `__real_fopen()`. This way you can "intercept" the call and massage it to you liking:

```
FILE* __wrap_fopen(const char* filename, const char* mode) {
    /* Do anthing you want, including changing arguments or not calling __real_fopen() at all. */
    FILE* result = __real_fopen(filename, mode);
    /* Do anthing you want, including changing the result. */
    return result;
}
```